# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-a_n x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} n a_n = \alpha > 0$. Let $f(x)$ be real-valued continuous function defined on $[0,\infty)$ with
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = k
\end{equation}
Evaluate
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-a_n x} dx
\end{equation}

I am totally lost on this. I "cheated" and pretend that $f(x) = k$. Then we get something like

$$(-k)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n a_n}\left( e^{-a_n \cdot\infty} - 1\right)$$

For the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-a_n x}}{n a_n} $, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n a_n = \alpha > 0$, at least we know that when $n$ is very big, $a_n$ should be positive. So this term is zero.

I don't know if my hand-waving argument is correct or not. In addition, what would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $t=\frac{x}{n}$, we get
$$ \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\infty}f(x)e^{-a_nx}\;dx=\int_0^{\infty}f(nt)e^{-na_nt}\;dt $$

If we define
$$g_n(t)=f(nt)e^{-na_nt}$$
then
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(t)=ke^{-\alpha t}$$
for all $t>0$. Moreover, $f$ is bounded since it is continuous with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=k$, and since $na_n\to \alpha>0$ we have $na_n>\frac{\alpha}{2}$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Therefore there is a constant $C$ such that
$$ |g_n(t)|\leq Ce^{-\frac{\alpha t}{2}} $$
for all $t\geq 0$ and all sufficiently large $n$, and since this function is integrable we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f(nt)e^{-na_nt}\;dt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}g_n(t)\;dt=\int_0^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(t)\;dt$$
$$ =k\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}\;dt=\frac{k}{\alpha}$$
which matches your "cheating" answer.

Comment: I spent some time reading about Dominated Convergence Theorem and now I know what you were talking about. Thank you.

Comment: Although I thought that we want some function $F$ such that $|g_n(t)| \le F(t)$ for _all_ $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If that bothers you, then you can change finitely many terms in the sequence $\{a_n\}$ so that $na_n>\frac{\alpha}{2}$ holds for all $n$. This will have no effect on the limit.

Comment: Is it possible to explicitly find an integrable $h(x)$ such that $\left| f(nt) e^{-n a_n t} \right| \le h(x)$ for all $n,t$?

Comment: Since all you know about $\{a_n\}$ is that $\lim na_n=\alpha>0$, you can't expect to be able to say something for all $n$. For instance, what if some of the $a_n$ are negative? The only thing that matters is the limiting behavior.

Comment: "what if some of the $a_n$ are negative?" That's what I thought, too. The best I could do was $\left| f(nt) e^{-n a_n t} \right| \le B_1 \left| e^{-na_n t}\right|$. I don't understand the "only thing that matters is the limiting behavior"... If I cannot find some $h(x)$ such that $B_1 \left| e^{-n a_n t}\right| \le h(x)$, then why can I use the theorem?

Comment: If $s_n$ is a sequence with $s_n\to s$, and $t_n$ is another sequence such that $t_n=s_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, then $t_n\to s$ as well. That's what I mean by the only thing that matters is the limiting behavior.

Comment: So in fact, we do _not_ need that $\left| f_n (x) \right| \le g(x)$ for all $x$ and all $n$. We just need for all $x$ and large $n$'s?

Comment: Sure, or as I said earlier, you can change finitely many of the $a_n$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Could you please tell me more about the constant $C$? How did you define it

Comment: how can we say $Ce^{\frac{-\alpha t}{2}}$ is integrable?

Comment: @NuwanPriyankara The actual value of $C$ is irrelevant, it is some upper bound on $|f|$. And one can show that $Ce^{-\frac{\alpha t}{2}}$ is integrable by computing its integral.